# gcsfuse not running command with set service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I am trying to mount a bucket using gscfuse, and the command is unable to be run from a service account.

When I run `gcloud auth list`, the service account is selected.

[image: selected account]

However, when I run the command `gcsfuse testing_bucket_images "$HOME/mount-folder"`, I receive the error

```
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running /usr/bin/fusermount: exit status 1
```

When I debugged the issue with this command `gcsfuse --foreground --debug_fuse --debug_fs --debug_gcs --debug_http -o nonempty new_cool_bucket /home/ACCOUNT_NAME_TEMP/path`,

this is the response

```
mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: fs.NewServer: create file system: SetUpBucket: Error in iterating through objects: googleapi: Error 403: ACCOUNT_NAME_TEMP does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., forbidden
```

however, the ACCOUNT_NAME_TEMP **is not the service account I am using**. It is my google account. How can I run this command with the service account?

Comment: What's the permission of your service account?

Comment: Run the command `gcloud auth application-default login` and try again. Applications use ADC (application default credentials) which are a different set of credentials from `gcloud auth login`. The latter authorizes the CLI.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere - the service account does have the google cloud storage permission that is needed of storage manager

Comment: @john haley - when i tried using that, it uses my own credentials, which does not have the permission to manage google storage. Only the service account has the permission.

Comment: `gcloud auth login` is for the CLI and does not provide credentials for gcsfuse. You will need to correctly setup `gcloud auth application-default login` with an account that has the required IAM roles, use the command flag `--key-file` or the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Comment: What are the roles? Cloud Storage permission means nothing!